# Mapping domain objects to resource objects in service layer or web layer?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, dozer

I am using Dozer to map my domain objects to resource objects (REST) which only contains the data. I am currently doing this mapping in my web layer. However should I move the translation to the service layer?

Comment: with given input I think Yes i would say you should do thatas web layer could change over the period and you should do in Service layer so that even any application communicate with your application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your architecture, but I guess that you have layers in a hierarchical order and access should only be allowed from a higher layer to a lower, right?!

Based on that assumption...

If you move the mapping to the service layer, the service layer will be aware of the REST API. Thus you introduce a dependency from a lower layer (service) to a higher layer (presentation). I guess this does not comply to your architecture, because a service layer's purpose is normally to provide a presentation free API to access domain logic. Thus I would not move the mapping to the service layer.

Comment: Thought so, I just started to think of it as an option.

Comment: And what about the security? Wouldn't it be problem if your entities are being accessed by WebService layer?